# Using spring framework with maven instead of ant

Tags: java, spring, maven-2, spring-mvc

Is there a tutorial somewhere which shows how to use spring framework with maven instead of ant? [This one](http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/) seems very good but it's all built with ant.

**EDIT**

I really don't know which answer to accept both are valid. I'll wait for some time let the community decide

Comment: you want to build spring with maven? or you have a project that uses spring.

Comment: I'm trying to learn spring, I feel more comfortable with maven than with ant since I'm using it already and its far more powerful than ant, thats why I ask

Comment: @duffymo I can distinguish between its and it's, just I'm in a rush sometimes so I can't really think of grammar(+not a native speaker), thank you for your edit though I'll try to improve my grammar next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the `build.xml` of the tutorial has 3 main targets :

- build the application
- deploy it on Tomcat server
- Unit testing using a in-memory database (hsqldb)

Regarding the first point, you will just need to create a `war` project on Maven. As you told in your comment, you are already using Maven in anothers projects, so I don't think it will cause you lots of troubles. You will just need to add the Spring dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

The second part concerns the deployment on Tomcat. Just use the [cargo plugin](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin) for that.

For the last point, you will just need to add the HSQLDB dependency in your `pom.xml`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Then, you will have to instanciate the database in one of your JUnit test case...

Answer (score 1):

If you already know maven, then you can quickly start working with spring using this archetype

> appfuse-basic-spring

Note that it sets everything up for Spring MVC, Spring and Hibernate so you should remove unnecessary files. Still, it's a great start.

If you don't know much about maven templates check [this URL](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html) that explains how to use archetypes. An archetype is basically a project template.

The complete list of templates can be found [here](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Archetypes+List).

Answer (score 1):

The Spring 3.0 samples are Maven based:

- https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/mvc-basic/trunk/
- https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/petclinic/trunk/
- https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/spring-travel/trunk/

Comment: The `pom.xml` in this project does not handle the auto-deployment on Tomcat. However, it manages the two other points, i.e. the build and the in-memory database unit testing.

Comment: @romaintaz Just use `mvn tomcat:run`, no need to setup cargo or anything.